# Tiny function to write array or string to a file for testing with MVC, Ajax, etc

Tags: php

This might not even warrant posting here, but I"m enjoying it and thought I would share.

```
//For Testing
function write_to_file($message){
        $handle = fopen("/path/to/logs/a_log_file.php", "a+");
        if (is_array($message)):
            fwrite($handle, "\nMessage is array.\t ");
            fclose($handle);
            file_put_contents('/path/to/logs/a_log_file.php', print_r($message, true),
                              FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        else:
            fwrite($handle, "\nMessage:\t " . $message);
            fclose($handle);
        endif;

        }
```

Haven't actually tested with multidimensional array yet and might be a good opportunity for some recursion.

Comments, suggestions and criticism are of course welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing `fwrite` and `file_put_contents` usage is a little strange, as they are functions which overlap in functionality. [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) in fact is just a wrapper to call `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose` - expanding that call to it's component parts would therefore make what the code is doing more obviously repetitive.

So, the first goal I would suggest is to avoid repeatedly opening the file to append text to it; the goal of the function is simply to append bytes to a file - so make the function do that, in one write call. An example of what I mean is:

```
function write_to_file($message)
{
    $header = "\nMessage:\t ";

    if (is_array($message)) {
        $header = "\nMessage is array.\n";
        $message = print_r($message, true);
    }

    file_put_contents(
        '/path/to/logs/a_log_file.php', 
        $header . $message, 
        FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
    );
}
```

Comment: very nice, and insightful as far as `file_put_contents`.